# Why Maven goal doesn't set variable to .properties file

Tags: java, maven

There is property file with 1 empty variable **config.properties**

```
url=
```

After executing maven goal

```
clean compile test -Durl=google.com
```

The variable remains empty. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because using -D your are passing the value as a system property, it will not be written in the file, but instead is accessible through `System.getProperty("url")`

Comment: so if i use in classes System.getProperty("url") it will return google.com?

Comment: Yes, but only if the property is pass in the command line execution